# Iterating through nested list / dictionary using Jinja2 templates

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, jinja2

I'm trying to dynamically configure multiple NFS servers in my system by generating their /etc/exports files using Ansible.  I'm hoping to be able to do this with a jinja2 template.  It's the jinja2 template that I can't figure out based on my exports list.

I have the following variables defined in my nfs role:

```yaml
site_nfs_servers: ['ansibletarget1', 'ansibletarget2']

exports:
  - server: "ansibletarget1"
    shares:
      - path: "/my/first/share/path"
        client: "*"
        options: "rw,sync"
      - path: "/my/second/share/path"
        client: "*"
        options: "rw,sync,root_squash"
  - server: "ansibletarget2"
    shares:
      - path: "/another/shared/path/different/server"
        client: "*"
        options: "ro,sync"
```

I then have the following ansible play to generate the template:

```yaml
- name: Generate the exports file.
  template:
    src: exports.j2
    dest: /etc/exports
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0750'
```

My template currently looks like this:

```jinja2
{% for export in exports %}
{% if ansible_hostname in export.server %}
{% for share in shares %}
{{ share.path }} {{ share.client }} {{ share.options }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't think I'm anywhere near close to having the correct template structure.  How on earth does one iterate through this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
[site_nfs_servers]
ansibletarget1
ansibletarget2
```

and put the *shares* into the *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/ansibletarget1.yml 
shares:
  - path: "/my/first/share/path"
    client: "*"
    options: "rw,sync"
  - path: "/my/second/share/path"
    client: "*"
    options: "rw,sync,root_squash"
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/ansibletarget2.yml 
shares:
  - path: "/another/shared/path/different/server"
    client: "*"
    options: "ro,sync"
```

Create a simplified role for testing

```sh
shell> tree roles/my_nfs_role/
roles/my_nfs_role/
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
└── templates
    └── exports.j2

2 directories, 2 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/my_nfs_role/tasks/main.yml 
- template:
    src: exports.j2
    dest: /etc/exports.test
```

```
shell> cat roles/my_nfs_role/templates/exports.j2 
{% for share in shares %}
{{ share.path }} {{ share.client }} {{ share.options }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, use the inventory group and the role in a playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: site_nfs_servers
  roles:
    - my_nfs_role
```

Run the playbook and create the files

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml

PLAY [site_nfs_servers] ************************************************

TASK [my_nfs_role : template] ******************************************
changed: [ansibletarget1]
changed: [ansibletarget2]
 ...
```

```sh
shell> ssh admin@ansibletarget1 cat /etc/exports.test
/my/first/share/path * rw,sync
/my/second/share/path * rw,sync,root_squash

shell> ssh admin@ansibletarget2 cat /etc/exports.test
/another/shared/path/different/server * ro,sync
```

See [Sample Ansible setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/sample_setup.html#sample-ansible-setup).

---

If you want to keep the shares in one object put the list into the *groups_vars*. To simplify the code, convert the list to a dictionary. You can use [community.general.groupby_as_dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html#grouping) for example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
exports:
  - server: "ansibletarget1"
    shares:
      - path: "/my/first/share/path"
        client: "*"
        options: "rw,sync"
      - path: "/my/second/share/path"
        client: "*"
        options: "rw,sync,root_squash"
  - server: "ansibletarget2"
    shares:
      - path: "/another/shared/path/different/server"
        client: "*"
        options: "ro,sync"

exports_dict: "{{ exports|community.general.groupby_as_dict('server') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  exports_dict:
    ansibletarget1:
      server: ansibletarget1
      shares:
      - client: '*'
        options: rw,sync
        path: /my/first/share/path
      - client: '*'
        options: rw,sync,root_squash
        path: /my/second/share/path
    ansibletarget2:
      server: ansibletarget2
      shares:
      - client: '*'
        options: ro,sync
        path: /another/shared/path/different/server
```

Then modify the template. This should create the same files as before.

```
shell> cat roles/my_nfs_role/templates/exports.j2 
{% for share in exports_dict[inventory_hostname]['shares'] %}
{{ share.path }} {{ share.client }} {{ share.options }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the reference to the `export` in your second loop.

```jinja2
{% for export in exports %}
{% if ansible_hostname in export.server %}
{% for share in export.shares %}
{{ share.path }} {{ share.client }} {{ share.options }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It would however be better to define the shares in host variables, as shown in the answer by Vladimir.